# Adding days to an ADUsers AccountExpirationDate

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Please Note: I am a newbie to Powershell

I would like to Get an ADusers AccountExpirationDate and Add 90days to the AD user's Expiration Date. Tried the

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $username | Set-ADAccountExpiration -TimeSpan 90.0:0
```

However, it adds 90 days to the current day under the AD user's account. Is there a way to specify adding 90 days to an `ADUser` `AccountExpirationDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works. If I understand correctly, you want to add 90 days to the current value of `AccountExpirationDate`.

```
$usr = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties AccountExpirationDate
$newExp = $usr.AccountExpirationDate.AddDays(90)

Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $usr -DateTime $newExp
```

Comment: Thank you, Santiago. That worked.  Hoping to get better with PowerShell with time. Any recommendations are appreciated.